# In R, how can I use sjPlot with cbind() outcome of glm model?

Tags: r, glm, sjplot

I'm trying to use `sjp.glm` [command](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.glm/) from `sjPlot` package to plot the results of glm model. All works fine until I specify y outcome as a vector of successes and failures, which is one of the way glm [can be called](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html).

To illustrate the problem

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)

# example from docs
y <- ifelse(efc$neg_c_7 < median(na.omit(efc$neg_c_7)), 0, 1)
# create data frame for fitting model
df <- data.frame(y = to_factor(y),
                 sex = to_factor(efc$c161sex),
                 dep = to_factor(efc$e42dep),
                 barthel = efc$barthtot,
                 education = to_factor(efc$c172code))

fit1 <- glm(y ~., data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# plot works
sjp.glm(fit1)

# similar as above but with aggregates
y0 <- ifelse(efc$neg_c_7 < median(na.omit(efc$neg_c_7)), 0, 1)
y1 <- ifelse(efc$neg_c_7 >= median(na.omit(efc$neg_c_7)), 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(y0 = y0, 
                 y1 = y1,
                 sex = to_factor(efc$c161sex),
                 dep = to_factor(efc$e42dep),
                 barthel = efc$barthtot,
                 education = to_factor(efc$c172code))

df_agg <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(sex, dep, barthel, education) %>%                            
  dplyr::summarise(c0=sum(y0),
                   c1=sum(y1))

fit2 <- glm(cbind(c0, c1) ~., data = df_agg, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# plot works not
sjp.glm(fit2)
```

Throws an error message:

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `sex`, `dep`, `barthel`
Error in cbind_all(x) : Argument 2 must be length 275, not 213
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown columns: `cbind(c0, c1)`
```

Any solutions for that?

Comment: Posted on github too https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/313

Comment: Author of the package pointed me on github to using `plot_model(fit2)` which replaces  `sjp.glm` and works with `cbind` outcome